# How to publish SharePoint Framework application to the Marketplace?

Tags: sharepoint-online, publish, spfx, marketplace, sharepointframework

I have created SharePoint Framework application. I need to publish that application to the SharePoint Marketplace.

I have refereed below link for the same,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/publish-to-marketplace-checklist

Can anyone share me the steps or share the demo application which published into the Marketplace?

Thanks in Advance